# How to deploy my VueCLI application on a Noje.js Server (Express)?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have build my project website with VueCLI so now i want to deploy my app on my server Node.js. 
The problem is :
- When I run the command build to get the dist folder and place it into my nodejs server i cant use my vue router because when for example :http://server.com/page1 it make a request to the server but i only want to get access to the page in the app with vue router.

'This is a single page website using vue router'

My node.js server example :

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();


app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')))

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
res.sendFile(__dirname+'/static/index.html')
})

app.listen('3000',()=>{
console.log("listen on port 3000");    
})

/site.com
/site.com/dist
/site.com/dist/css
/site.com/dist/js
/site.com/dist/index.html
/site.com/index.js //server nodejs
```

I want to be able to get access to the internal pages of my vue router website.
For the moment when im asking in the url for a page it ask the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a project organization issue. I would advice you generate your dist outside your app. and have

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/static')))
```

Point to dist instead of static i.e.

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/path/to/dist')))
```

Comment: I have committed a miss take when I wrote. I will update my post.

Comment: The server is only here to serve the index.html file then all the orthers request by the users must be handle by vue router.

Answer (score 0):

- So apparently to solve my problem i have to install and configure a
  Middleware call "connect-history-api-fallback" from github
  'https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback'. This API
  is only for a server running on Node.js and using express (this is my
  case).

---

- But if you want to configure your server nginx,apache ... All you
  need to do is found your conf on the official web page
  'https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations'.

Hope this will help you =)